# BIRT Eclipse - cannot recognize input near '?'

Tags: eclipse, hive, birt

birt 4.6.0

I have the following query, which works in both BIRT and DBVizualizer:

```
SELECT t1.keys as SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE, t1.vals as previous_count, t2.vals as current_count from (
        SELECT explode(map('Row Total', SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE_TOTAL)) as (keys, vals)
        FROM my_table
        WHERE src_file_dt = '1222') t1,
(
        SELECT explode(map('Row Total', SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE_TOTAL)) as (keys, vals)
        FROM my_table
        WHERE src_file_dt = '5221') t2
where t1.keys = t2.keys
```

But when I parametarize it it gives me the following error

```
[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:246 cannot recognize input near '?' ')' 't1' in expression specification:17:16
```

query like:

```
SELECT t1.keys as SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE, t1.vals as previous_count, t2.vals as current_count from (
        SELECT explode(map('Row Total', SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE_TOTAL)) as (keys, vals)
        FROM my_table
        WHERE src_file_dt = ?) t1,
(
        SELECT explode(map('Row Total', SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE_TOTAL)) as (keys, vals)
        FROM my_table
        WHERE src_file_dt = ?) t2
where t1.keys = t2.keys
```

I even try it as one line:

```
SELECT t1.keys as SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE, t1.vals as previous_count, t2.vals as current_count from (SELECT explode(map('Row Total', SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE_TOTAL)) as (keys, vals) FROM my_table WHERE src_file_dt = ?) t1, (SELECT explode(map('Row Total', SUBSCRIBER_COMPLETE_TOTAL)) as (keys, vals) FROM my_table WHERE src_file_dt = ?) t2 where t1.keys = t2.keys
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to make it work. It seems to be a [bug in Eclipse/BIRT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371540)

I was able to work around it by replacing the variables in the query in the beforeOpen script for the Data Set like

```
this.queryText = String(queryText).replace("'prev'", params["PREV_DATE"]);
this.queryText = String(queryText).replace("'curr'", params["CURR_DATE"]);
```